# How to set the text of a previously-created NSMutableString?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsmutablestring

I have an `NSMutableString` called `makeString`. I want to create it at the beginning of my program without having to set its text. I then want to be able to set its text. I am currently using the following to create it.

```
NSMutableString *make2String = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
```

I am then using the following to set its text value.

```
make2String = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Gold.png"];
```

Is this ok to do or is there a better way to set an `NSMutableString`'s text?

Comment: Can you make your question a question? i.e. "Is this ok to do or is there a better way to set an NSMutableString's text**?**"

Comment: Since you seem to be using a string to hold a filename you might find using `NSString` preferable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not ok, you are replacing your mutable string with an ordinary immutable string (and leaking the original mutable string in the process). You could do `[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Gold.png"]` after releasing the old string if you wanted to go that route. Or you could use NSMutableString's `setString:` method to set the content.

But if you're not actually mutating the string and just assigning different strings, you don't need NSMutableString at all. Just do `make2String = @"Gold.png";` and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
  NSMutableString * aString = [NSMutableString alloc];
  aString = [aString init];
  [aString setString:@"yourText"];
  [aString setString:@"yourNewText"];
  [aString setString:@"yourNewNewText"];
  //...
  [aString release];
```

Comment: Breaking up the alloc/init pair is bad form.

Comment: @Josh: I know. I'm unusual in finding nested messages hard on the eye.

Answer (score 0):

`make2String = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Gold.png"];`

**FYI:** This is how I allocate NSMutableStrings without setting text

`NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];`